# Using Getters from Nested Structure In Streams

Tags: list, data-structures, java-8, maps, java-stream

I am converting a `List<City>` into a `Map<CityType, Set<City>>`.

City within it has fields like `CityIdentifier, State, Latitude` etc.

`CityIdentifier` within it has a `cityName` & `cityType`.

For the above conversion, for the `Collectors.groupingBy`, I need a function like `City::getCityType`. Can I use the getter from `CityIdentifier` i.e. something like `City::getCityIdentifier.getCityType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a method reference in this example.

Use a lambda expression instead:

```
city -> city.getCityIdentifier().getCityType()
```

And the full pipeline:

```
Map<CityType, Set<City>> map =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(city -> city.getCityIdentifier().getCityType(),
                                       Collectors.toSet()));
```